# In VB looking to clear text boxes in a panel only

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with many text boxes and I am looking to code a button that will clear only a portion of these boxes, I have inserted a panel to contain those that I require to be effected and have been using the following code:

```
  Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim txt As TextBox
    For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls
        If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
            txt = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
            txt.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I am able to code it so that it clears ALL text boxes, but it is where I have added 'Panel1.Controls.Clear()' seems to be where I am going wrong? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ`'s [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to find and cast the relevant TextBoxes:

```
For Each txt In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    txt.Text = ""
Next
```

So you don't need `Panel1.Controls.Clear()` at all, it removes all controls from the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. You should use the ctrl variable in your for statement and clear it's text.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each ctrl As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
            ctrl.Text = "" 'You just need to add this.
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this and it is still not doing anything sadly, am I supposed to connect the text boxes and panel some how, ?

Comment: Yes. The text boxes needs to be places on top of the panel.

Comment: Yeah lol thought so, they were already on top I was just wondering if there is somthing Im not doing

Comment: That's very strange. Do this just to make 100% sure that the text boxes is properly on the panel: MsgBox(TextBox1.Parent.ToString)

Comment: If TypeOf(ctrl) Is TextBox Then